# Move values after comma to newline to text file

Tags: php, mysql

I have values in my database that has values with commas. Eg:

Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday. When I call the row from the database where certain id, I want to write the the result to a text file after every comma into a new line as follows:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

One below the other.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Comment: Is it too late to just fix the database design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace comma with newline and write to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921636/replace-comma-with-newline-and-write-to-text-file). OP re-asked this question with better accuracy for the actual project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function.

[explode](http://php.net/explode) — Split a string by string

```
$days   = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday";
$weekdays = explode(",", $days);

foreach( $weekdays as $value ){
    echo $value."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

I think it will work for you!

Comment: I have tried the above code snippet but when displayed on browser it show the days of the week next to each other with spaces which is not a problem as I need the result to be written on a txt file. When I used the above snippet to write $value to a txt file only Sunday was added on the txt file. Please help

Comment: @CoderJoe, You need to add txt file code in the foreach loop.And then check it again.

Comment: I have done that but doesn't work unless I've done it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$result   = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday";
$array = explode(",", $result);

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo $value."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

explode function will help you

```
$str = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday";
    $val = explode(",",$str);


    foreach ($val as $key=>$value) {

      echo $value.'</br>';
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above snippet and it works on the browser, how would I write the result to a txt file showing one below the other? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$colVal = $row['col-name'];    
echo str_replace(",", "\r\n", $colVal);
```