# Replace comma with newline and write to text file

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take value on the database and replace the comma with a newline and then write to a text file.

Example:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE ID = 6
Result: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
```

I want it to then remove the commas and write to a .txt file with newline.

Result:

```
Monday

Tuesday

Wednesday

Thursday

Friday
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `str_replace` obviously.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried out till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
file_put_contents("file.txt", str_replace(",", "\r\n", $string));
```

Comment: Did you just copy my code and replaced the PHP_EOL part? You could at least try to "hide" it by changing filename and replacing the capital F my phone puts on the file_put_contents()

Answer (score 0):

File_put_contents saves the file file.txt. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
Str_replace replace the commas with new line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
File_put_contents("file.txt", str_replace(",", PHP_EOL, $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you know how to execute your query and fetch the result:

it basically comes to the function str_replace. (could also be replaced in the query using mysql's REPLACE() function)

```
<?php
  file_put_contents('/myfile.txt', str_replace(',', PHP_EOL, $row['column']));
```

But your question is quit limited in information.

btw: should the file not be overwritten: Use FILE_APPEND as 3rd parameter of file_put_contents